# How to disable a specific dropdownmenu item value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown, disable

**Disable dropDown value in Flutter**

`policyDropdown = ['Platinum', 'Gold', 'Sr. Citizen'],`

```
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Policy Type'),
                      trailing: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          value: policyDropdownData,
                          items: policyDropdown.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(value),
                              value: value,
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              policyDropdownData = value.toString();
                              
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

disable the first data of the policyDropdown... What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `enable` property of the `DropdownMenuItem` and enable every other option than the first one of your `policyDropdown` list i.e."**Platinum**".

for example:

```dart
return DropdownMenuItem(
  value: value,
  child: Text(value),
  enabled: value != 'Platinum',
);
```

Additionally, If you want users to know that the option is disabled you can change the color of the text using the same logic.

```dart
return DropdownMenuItem(
  value: value,
  child: Text(
    value,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: value != 'Platinum'
          ? Colors.white
          : Colors.white60,
    ),
  ),
  enabled: value != 'Platinum',
);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It is working good.... but I need to disable any one option... this disable whole dropdown values

Comment: The above code will only disable `Platinum` within the drop-down.

Comment: Added a working gif as well in the answer.

Comment: its working nice